# Drop down not showing value in IE

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

The first dropdown "Select device" is not showing any value in IE:

```
<div class="select-container"> 
<SELECT Id="Device" name="device" onchange="javascript:LoadDevice(this.value);">
</SELECT>
```

```
<div class="select-container" id="Model">
<SELECT name="model" ><OPTION>Select Model</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Please check the HTML entire page here: http://goo.gl/1kEc2J

It works in all other browsers.

The dropdown gets its value from an external PHP page.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It works for me in IE10.

Comment: It has problems on older versions.

Comment: Yes, it works in IE10, FF, Chrome etc. but not in IE 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find this line in slicious.php

```
devicer +='<option value="'+i+'" onclick="javascript:LoadDevice('+i+');">'+aDevice[i]';
```

should be

```
devicer +='<option value="'+i+'" onclick="javascript:LoadDevice('+i+');">'+aDevice[i]+'</option>';
```

you missed to close option tag

Answer (score 0):

Your site is wrong on so many levels. But to your problem that you've listed here.

remove all of the `"javascript:` text from your events as these are not needed.

remove the onclick statements from 
`<option value="1" onclick="javascript:LoadDevice(1);">iPhone</option>`

Why are you doing this?

```
<script src="http://www.mobiltelefoner.dk/tst/slicious.php" type="text/javascript">
```

when the slicious.php is actually a javascript file?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me.

I have removed the "javascript:" I will remove the onclick now